# Compiling C library for android, but no symbols found

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, static-libraries

I am trying to compile a simple C library for android, but the resulting library doesn't contain any symbols/objects! I am checking the library using `nm` command.

This is the Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := my_lib_static
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libmylib

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := File1.c File2.c 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
# or include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

**EDIT**:

A subfolder called "objs" is created, which has all the symbols.

**EDIT**:

This is the output of `gobjdump`:

```
MyLibBot.o:     file format elf32-littlemips

gobjdump: MyLibBot.o: not a dynamic object
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols



MyLibCommon.o:     file format elf32-littlemips

gobjdump: MyLibCommon.o: not a dynamic object
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols



MyLibGameLogic.o:     file format elf32-littlemips

gobjdump: MyLibGameLogic.o: not a dynamic object
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols



MyLibUndoStack.o:     file format elf32-littlemips

gobjdump: MyLibUndoStack.o: not a dynamic object
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

Comment: Sounds like the library is getting stripped.  What happens if you declare the functions you want to export as JNIEXPORT ?  Even if you aren't intending to call them via JNI, that should get them preserved.  Or you can look up how the NDK actually defines that and do something similar yourself.  If really stuck, build hello-jni from the NDK samples, then make a copy of it and morph it bit by bit into your project until it breaks, at which point you will realize what the problem is.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I already looked at the samples, that's how I am building this library.

Comment: That's why I suggested modifying a tested copy of the sample into your project, until you find the difference that makes it no longer build correctly.

Comment: I have no idea what "gojdump" is, but it is not the tool you should be using.  You should be using the architecture-os-abi- prefixed version of nm or objdump provided in the ndk, with the -D or -T flag respectively, to examine the .so file.

Comment: `find ~/Developer/Libs/android/android-ndk-r9d -name "*nm"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify the -D flag to nm if you want it to display dynamic symbols.

You can also use the -T flag to objdump

You should use the versions of nm or objdump provided in the ndk, not any versions which might be found for managing libraries of the development host.  These will be found buried far under the toolchains/ folder of the ndk and will have prefixed names something like `arm-linux-androideabi-nm`

For example, (on a system I haven't used for Android work in a while, so containing a stale version - you will have to use some ingenuity to find what is applicable on your system):

```
$NDK/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm -D mylibrary.so
```

Comment: Ah, that's an additional problem, you have to use the versions of these tools which ship in the ndk, NOT those provided for managing libraries on the host.

Comment: OK, I did as you suggest. Updating question.

Comment: Regardless of clang vs gcc, try them anyway.  The **.so file** format at least has to be compatible, otherwise it wouldn't work on the device.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this... I am just so stressed from this problem... The symbols are there, so the linking isn't happening, I guess.

Comment: Make sure the current version of the file is getting unpacked on the device, triple check the name of the function sought vs. the name of the one provided by the library bearing in mind all the java package prefixing, watch out for illegal characters, etc.

Comment: What's killing me is that it works on iOS and Mac. Not on Android.

Comment: That's not unexpected - while you have a C compiler and a more or less unix environment in both cases, there are a *lot* of differences required to get a working setup in which to run the portable part of your code.  Perhaps you should post a question with your actual goal and difficulty.

Comment: OMG... I was actually linking the iOS project against an older version of the library, which didn't have those symbols......... I wanna shoot myself.

Comment: What's the difference between **nm** and **gobjdump**?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue. You can workaround with a custom build so that -lotherlib gets passed as final argument. For example:

```
$ /path/to/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
--sysroot=/path/to/platforms/android-19/arch-arm \
-L/usr/local/src/lua-5.1.5/src -shared -lm -o mylibrary.so milibrary.o \
-lotherlib
```

I'm not a C expert so this took me days to figure out :P, not sure why -l should go at the very end...